# calling an instance by a string in c#

Tags: c#

I am new at c# and I have a little problem completing my code, I have seen a lot of cases similar to mine, they have been solved by reflection but it didn't work with me.

I have a class which could results two strings and a double as an example 
it results:

```
room = "bedroom";

device = "TV";

status = ON;  //on =100 double
```

I have another class which is called Room that has the devices as functions of one double variable, examples :

```
Room bedroom = new Room();   
bedroom.lights(ON);
livingroom.TV(OFF);
kitchen.lights(OFF);
```

The first class could return any room or any device or any statues so there is a lot of probabilities so I want the three variables from the first class to be turned into a line of code like the examples of the other class:

A simple example for I want:

```
room = "bedroom";
device = "TV";
status = ON; // double ON = 100;
```

to be this :

```
bedroom.TV(ON);
```

If there is another way to do that instead of turning strings into code I don't mind ^_^

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but you maybe want something like a room class that stores a list of devices and every device has function `On` and `Off` and each device has it's name and status and the room variable is just a parent of the device in this case. If so you could also use interface such as `IDevice` with functions `On` and `Off` and every device (tv, lamp, microwave) would derive from `IDevice`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use your syntax. I'm not even sure if it's possible, maybe with some weird reflection stuff.
How about this syntax:

```
bedroom("TV", ON );
```

where `bedroom` is an instance of a `room` class.
Then, your `room` class would contain a `Dictionary<string,status>`, so that you can add devices like TVs, lights, whatever you like, and set their ON/OFF status.

If your choice of possible devices is limited, e.g. only TVs and lights, then you could work with reflection, but IMO it's not worth the hassle.